# Cannot call Linux command using system function in c

Tags: c, linux

I want to execute following command with `system()` function,

```
awk -F [][] '/dB/ { print $2 }' <(amixer sget Master) > sound_level
```

It gives me the desired output when I write in the terminal.
But when I call this command with system function in C it gives me error.

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        system("awk -F [][] '/dB/ { print $2 }' <(amixer sget Master) > sound_level");
        return 0;
}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I have also tried:

```
awk -F [][] '/dB/ { print $2 }' < /(amixer sget Master /) > sound_level
```

but it does not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show the code where you are trying to use this in the program. The `system` call

Comment: system("awk -F [][] '/dB/ { print $2 }' <(amixer sget Master) > sound_level");

Comment: BTW: The `system()` function is something different than a system call.

Comment: Ulrich Eckhardt thank you for you suggestion.I have edited the question.

Comment: Concerning the code, please edit your question to include a full `main()` function, but stripped of really everything that is not necessary to reproduce the problem. Nothing of what you have shown here is the cause of the error you get.

Comment: perhaps because when you execute in the terminal you use bash, whereas the error message is running it with sh shell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html). That C function (which you probably should avoid, prefer explicit [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) like `fork` & `execve`) is running the POSIX `/bin/sh -c` ; read also [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).

But your interactive shell is probably `bash` which behaves differently than POSIX `sh`, notably for redirections like `<(amixer sget Master)`

To make things more complex, the `/bin/bash` *program*, when invoked as `sh`, changes it behavior to POSIX `sh`, so on many systems, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash` ...

So read also the documentation of [GNU `bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/),  and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/), and [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) ...

Then, either set up your pipelines and redirections with explicit [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), or code some `bash` or `zsh` script (but probably not a POSIX `/bin/sh` one!) to do the work.

I don't know what `amixer sget Master`  does, but perhaps you might consider a pipeline like

```
 amixer sget Master | awk -F '[][]' '/dB/ { print $2 }'
```

<sup>(and the above pipeline is POSIX `sh` compatible, so callable from [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)...)</sup>

I am surprised you need to do all that. I guess that the sound volume could be queried by some pseudo file from `/sys/`

Learn more about [ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/) and read some [*Guide thru the Linux sound API*](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/guide-to-sound-apis.html)

Comment: Don't do that. Either code some `bash` or `zsh` (but not `sh` !!!) shell script and run it from `system`, or use explicit [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Comment: Also worth knowing that you can start a shell with [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) and feed it a script to its standard input from within your C program. That way, you don't need an extra file (that might not be available). Of course, you should only do that for very tiny scripts.